# Conditionally install a Python package on Google Colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

On Google Colab, every time a runtime is closed, I need to reinstall some Python packages. This can be not very pleasant.

How can I install these packages conditionally?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this code worked just fine:

```
# conditional install yahoo_fin
try:
  import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
except ModuleNotFoundError:
  if 'google.colab' in str(get_ipython()):
    %pip install yahoo_fin

  import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
```